# How to pass a urlRoot to a model in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I need to pass a `urlRoot` to a model at runtime, as several different classes of the model use different `urlRoot`s.

Here is my model:

```
App.Models.Table = Backbone.Model.extend({ });
```

And here is where I am going to use it:

```
var m = new App.Models.Table();
var t = new App.Collections.Tables(m, { url: this.url });
var tables = new App.Views.Tables({ collection: t, template: this.template });
```

`this.url` returns the correct value, based on the event that calls it.  Am I passing my model into the collection wrong?  Here is my collection:

```
App.Collections.Tables = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: this.url,
    model: App.Models.Table,
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        if (options && options.url) {
            this.url = options.url;
        }
        this.fetch({
              success: function(data, options) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

How do I pass in `this.url` to my model?

Comment: At runtime, when I run the click event, I get an error that a URL must be defined.

Comment: what is this ? i mean what this is refering to ?

Comment: I'm just trying to pass a urlRoot into my model.  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: If I put a string in with the correct path for the `urlRoot`, my app works.  But I need to be able to change the `urLRoot`at runtime, based on the route.

Comment: where urlRoot is defined. if it is outside Table you need to use the self trick , var self = this , then pass urlRoot:self.urlRoot

Comment: Same error: Error: `A "url" property or function must be specified`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `this.url` is the correct url in your example, then do the following:

```
table = new App.Models.Table({
    id: id
});
table.urlRoot = this.url;
```

Comment: I still get `A "url" property or function must be specified` even if I hard code a string for `m.urlRoot`

Comment: A couple of factual errors you might want to look at: `urlRoot:this.urlRoot` is not the same as `a = a`, because the value of `this` is the context at point of calling extend, most likely window. It's still wrong of course. Also the way he passes `url` to collection is fine, because it's the second argument (options) it's assigned to the instance in the constructor.

Comment: @fencliff, how do I accomplish this above?

Comment: @sehummel, I think you'd benefit from reading about the `this` context variable in javascript so that you really understand it. I would also recommend going through the Backbone documentation with time and care, and maybe trying out some tutorials.

Comment: @sehummel I think a tutorial might be a good way to learn. I haven't read this one, but I've seen it recommended often: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/. Also https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone/js

Comment: I am trying.  Thank you for your help.  I'll check those out.

Comment: Those didn't answer my question, but thanks for the references.

Comment: @fencliff You know, you're totally right about the `this` bit. Had a brain fart there. And yeah, you're right about the collection url stuff too. Guess I didn't look closely enough at his collection constructor. I think you're right... It seems like this question has more to do with understanding `this` than anything else.

Comment: It still isn't setting my urlRoot doing that.

Comment: Even when I hardcode a value for the urlRoot, it still doesn't work.  I don't think you can add a urlRoot in that manner.

Comment: You're right.  OK.  Back to the drawing board.  My problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22611/discussion-between-lukas-and-sehummel)

Answer (score 2):

The URL should be either a string constant or a function that returns a string.  In your collection, you'd want to do something like:

```
App.Collections.Tables = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() { return "http://my.url/" },
    // or, url: "http://my.url"
});
```

Using an anonymous function gives you the ability to process some data (that is, potentially modify the string) before the request is sent out.

Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Well, I need to be able to pass in a string as my urlRoot